# Why the ring finger is called the third finger?

Tags: etymology

I’ve long puzzled about why the ring finger is called third finger in spite of it being the forth finger from the thumb (counting the thumb as the first, the pointing finger the second, the middle finger as the third) and the second from the little finger.

Wikipedia describes it as;

> **the fourth** proximal digit of the human hand, and **the second** most ulnar
>   finger, located between the middle finger and the little finger. It is
>   also called digitus medicinalis, the fourth finger, digitus annularis,
>   digitus quartus, or digitus IV in anatomy. In Chinese it’s called 无名指
>   - unnamed finger.

Nothing is related with “the third.”

We Japanese also call the ring finger "薬指- kusuri-yubi" meaning the finger (only) used for tasting and examining medicine.

How did the ring finger come to be called the third finger?

**For your refference;**

Cambridge online English Dictionary defines finger as “**One of the five** long parts at the end of your hand.”

Oxford online English Dictionary defines finger as “**Each of the four** slender jointed parts attached to either hand, **or five**, if the thumb is included.

Merriam-Webster English Dictionary defines finger as “**One of the five** long parts of the hand that are used for holding things; especially: **one of the four** that are not the thumb.”

Comment: It's not "the forth finger from the thumb", it's the third finger from the thumb. Your thumb is a digit, but not a finger.

Comment: See [Is a thumb also a finger?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/is-a-thumb-also-a-finger)

Comment: When native English speakers count on their fingers, they count: index, middle, ring, pinky, thumb. The ring finger is the *third* finger. I've heard this differs in other cultures.

Comment: @RegDwight. At least Japanese think it one of five fingers. We never think it a stand-alone (as thumb) or separete organ (protrude) from fingers.

Comment: @PeterShor As it happens, I don't do it that way, I start with the thumb, then index and so on. As for the OP's question, my experience is that people don't use ordinal names for the fingers, rather they use the names Peter gives.

Comment: Cont. We call the thumb 親指-parent finger, the pointing finger 人差し指-pointing finger, the middle finger 中指-middle finger, the ring finger-薬指、and the little finger 小指the little finger in Japanese.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that according to this link the meaning of "third finger" differs between UK and US English. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third_finger

Comment: @Rupe I was not aware that Americans called the middle finger the 'third finger'. In the UK it is definitely the one between the middle and the little finger. Of course, if the thumb is not a finger, how can there be a middle finger - of four? But since we are on the subject. On a further matter, why is the 'index finger' so called?

Comment: @Rupe: [this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4iqya_counting-with-your-fingers-in-engli_news), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger-counting) say you're doing it the Western European way, and not the English way.

Comment: @PeterShor Gosh, I never knew there was a "proper" way to do it. I am one-eighth French - never realised it was being expressed in any way :)

Comment: @WS2 Re "index finger"... same reason it's the "pointing finger", only in Latin.

Comment: Anyone who plays the violin or the cello will be aware that the fingers on the left hand are numbered 1, 2, 3 and 4 (with the thumb not included in the numbering). However, piano fingering is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (with the thumb included in the numbering) - although in the past there was something called 'English fingering' with +, 1, 2, 3, 4. The current system was known as 'Continental fingering'. The details are in the Wikipedia article on fingering: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingering.

Comment: To muddy the water a bit, one would not include the thumb in counting if that is your reference point - to say that a particular finger is *x* positions **from** the thumb assumes that the thumb is *not* counted. Because the thumb is unique among the fingers, it makes a good reference point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is that the thumb is not a finger. Otherwise it would not be called thumb but first finger.

In German a germanic language just like English we have:

1. Thumb --> Daumen
2. Index finger --> Zeigefinger
3. Middle finger (the finger) --> Mittelfinger
4. Fourth finger / Ring finger --> Ringfinger
5. Pinky --> Kleiner Finger (small finger)

As you can see the thumb is not called finger. So the first finger would be the index finger.

Why is this the first? Because it is the most used.

Comment: I think it's basically the issue of the  difference of culture. I don't know about the notion of fingers among the nations of other world. To us (Japanese) the thumb is difinately a finger, not the special finger, and we don't other word than finger.

Comment: If the thumb is not a finger, why is the big toe still a toe??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Because the great toe is not opposable in modern humans, that’s why.  The thumb is.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent The difference is akin to the term 'car' in english language. For an english speaker a lorry is not a car, while most often 'car' it translated to other languages the same as 'automobile', which, of course, is a superset. But strange things happen when people try to count everything. For example, when people say "We use decimal, because we have ten fingers" they count a thumb as a finger. Or "When crossing the road, first check for cars" nobody would reply "So i should ignore any lorry that i see".

Comment: @Volodya: that reminds me of a joke about a country where they drive on the left, and have plans to switch to the right. The instructions are: *"We will do a provisionary trial. On January 1 of 2015, all cars start driving on the right side of the road. If this appears to working after a year, then on January 1 of 2016, lorries will also switch to the right side."*